# cannot find file in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, office-interop

Making a MVC (.Net5.0) that exports data to word. Did the same using webforms which worked fine but when doing it in MVC, a 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException. Ths system cannot find file specified' error pops up. I can't find whats wrong as I located my files the same way in console app and web form or is there some other way to locate local file in MVC?? No matter what libraby I use, the code works fine on webforms/console app but has the same problem on MVC. Can anyone tell me how to locate local files/directories in MVC. Thankyou for your time.

```
FileName= "office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"  string

StackTrace="
at findandreplacemvc.Controllers.DocxController.CreateWordDocument(Object filename, Object SaveAs) 
in D:\\Files\\C#\\findandreplacemvc\\findandreplacemvc\\Controllers\\DocxController.cs:line 113\r\n   
at findandreplacemvc.Controllers.DocxController.generateDocx() in D:\\Files\\C#\\findandreplacemvc\\findandreplacemvc\\Controllers\\DocxController.cs:line 24\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()" string
```

Code:

```
public class DocxController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult generateDocx()
        {
            var f1 = @"D:\docs\templateFile.docx";
            var f2 = @"D:\docs\replacedFile.docx";
            CreateWordDocument(f1 , f2);
            return Ok("done");
        }

        private void FindAndReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp, object findText, object replaceWithText)
        {
            //options
            object matchCase = true;

            object matchwholeWord = true;

            object matchwildCards = false;

            object matchSoundLike = false;

            object nmatchAllforms = false;

            object forward = true;

            object format = false;

            object matchKashida = false;

            object matchDiactitics = false;

            object matchAlefHamza = false;

            object matchControl = false;

            object read_only = false;

            object visible = true;

            object replace = 2;

            object wrap = 1;

            wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase,
                                            ref matchwholeWord, ref matchwildCards, ref matchSoundLike,

                                            ref nmatchAllforms, ref forward,

                                            ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,

                                                ref replace, ref matchKashida,

                                            ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza,

                                             ref matchControl);
        }

        private void CreateWordDocument(object filename, object SaveAs)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            object missing = Missing.Value;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document myWordDoc = null;

            if (System.IO.File.Exists((string)filename))
            {
                object readOnly = false;

                object isvisible = false;

                wordApp.Visible = false;
                myWordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly,
                                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                     ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                myWordDoc.Activate();

                //Find and Replace
                this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "varName", "Anything");
                this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "varAddress", "Anything");

                myWordDoc.SaveAs2(ref SaveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                myWordDoc.Close();
                wordApp.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `FileNotFoundException` has a `Filename` property that will tell you the exact file it was looking for. Catch the exception, and update your question with the filename, _and also the full stacktrace_.

Comment: `webforms which worked fine` did it? For starters, using Word on a web server requires a license for every single user, anonymous or not. This code fails to properly dispose the COM objects, especially in case of errors, which means this will leave orphaned Word instances, eating up the server's memory. There's no need to use Word Interop in the first place. `docx` is a ZIP file containing well defined XML documents. Since 2007 it's possible to create a `docx` document without Word, either by using the [Open Office XML SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk)

Comment: There are libraries that simplify working with the OOXML format as well. If you [search for docx in NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=docx) you'll find over 200 results. Some libraries are open source, some free, some commercial

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm a starter and for now don't care that much on memory consumption as its just for learning. The same code works fine on webforms and console apps. And about DocX, similar problem occurs there too i.e. file not found/directory problems on MVC but ran fine on Console app. What I think is there is a different way of locating local files in a mvc project and because I could'nt find it/understand it elsewhere, I decided to ask here. Thankyou for your time.

Comment: @dotdot a path error means you used the wrong path. It has nothing at all to do with MVC. Perhaps there's no `D:` perhaps there's no Word. Or your application pool account has no permission to write to `D:\Files\C#\`. An app pool account only has permission to write to the web app's folder, no matter what stack is used

Comment: What's at `DocxController.cs:line 113`? Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos.. That's where I am confused because the same exact path name works while doing it in console app or webforms. If the path didn't work for the others, it would've been an easy solution but the fact it works on webform and not on MVC is making me confused. And thankyou for you time and effort sir.

Answer (score 1):

**FileNotFoundException.**

This has nothing to do with MVC. MVC is old enough to go to high school (released 2009) so if there was such a problem every .NET developer would have run into it years ago.

Some path is wrong or the web app has no permission to read from that path. Without knowing which line threw it's hard to say what may be the problem.

- App pool accounts only have permission to read files in the web app's folder. This ins't an MVC issue, IIS itself enforces that restriction. When using IIS Express for debugging this may not be obvious though.
- The folder may not exist.
- The template file may not exist

**Generating Word Documents**

This didn't really work with WebForms either, for several reasons:

- You need a Word license for every single user of the web site, even if they're anonymous.
- It's way too easy to leave orphaned Word versions in memory, eating up the server's memory until it crawls to a stop
- The code doesn't close Word in case of errors nor does it dispose the COM objects, resulting in orphaned Word instances.

You don't need Word to create Word documents. Since 2007 the `docx` format allows applications to create proper documents directly. `docx` is a ZIP contained XML files in a well defined format. You can create these files directly, use Microsoft's [Open Offixe XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) or a library like [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/) to generate Word files with just a few lines. If you [search NuGet for docx](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=docx) you'll find over 200 results. NPOI is probably the most popular with 13M downloads.

The [text replacement example](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi-examples/blob/main/xwpf/ReplaceTexts/Program.cs) does the same thing as your program in less than 10 lines:

```
        var template = @"Template1.docx";
        using (var rs = File.OpenRead(template))
        {

            var generateFile = @"output1.docx";
            using (var ws = File.Create(generateFile))
            {
                var doc = new XWPFDocument(rs);

                foreach (var para in doc.Paragraphs)
                {
                    foreach (var placeholder in placeHolderDictionary)
                    {
                        if (para.ParagraphText.Contains(placeholder))
                        {
                            para.ReplaceText(placeholder, "Nissl");
                        }
                    }
                }
                doc.Write(ws);
            }
        }
```

The file is saved to a stream with `doc.Write(ws)`. That stream could easily be the *Response* stream in either WebForms or MVC, allowing you to send the file directly to the browser.